# Module compiled with swift X.1 cannot be imported in Swift X.0.2

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Swift 3.1 came out and I'm receiving this error message in my project:

> Module compiled with swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2

So how do I tell Xcode to start updating my project and migrate it to Swift 3.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely that you are including 3rd party frameworks/libraries. Those are what need to be updated/recompiled.  If you are using Carthage or Pods you should just rebuild those libraries and make them available to your app. The problem isn't your code. When you compile it, it will compile to 3.1

Answer (score 3):

[etayluz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545308/etayluz)

Upgrade your Xcode to 8.3 and your Swift version will be 3.1

I use Carthage to update library/framework again, with option **--no-use-binaries**

```
carthage update --no-use-binaries
```

Answer (score 1):

These steps helped me.

These things happens sometimes when your Xcode doesn't support certain version of your third party dependencies. 
Try to use proper version of your third party dependencies compatible with Xcode version.

1. Clear your Derived data in Xcode. Xcode -> File -> Workspace settings -> Click on the grey arrow mark beside Derived data.
2. Check carthage version by running `carthage version`. It should be above 0.20.0. Run `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` in your terminal. Gets rid of compatibility issues.
3. Clean your project. Command + Shift + K. Then build and run.