# Module compiled with Swift 3.0.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1 PaperOnboarding

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am using a framework called "PaperOnboarding" I have imported it into my Xcode project using CocoaPods I have imported it into my swift code but I get an Error:

> /Users/xxx/Desktop/take01/take 01/walkthrough.swift:10:8: Module compiled with Swift 3.0.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1:
>
> /Users/xxx/Desktop/take01/take 
>       01/PaperOnboarding.framework/Modules/PaperOnboarding.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

I am running Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 3.1.

Comment: I just imported the Onboarding in my project few days ago. I went with the manual approach, might want to try that!

Comment: All modules need to be compiled at the same level, so you should re-run your cocoa pods command. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238856/module-compiled-with-swift-3-1-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-2/43239043#43239043

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238856/module-compiled-with-swift-3-1-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-2)